# How do I programmatically convert putty logs to human-readable, searchable files?

Tags: command-line-interface, log-files, shell-scripting, putty, grep

**Background:** 
I have a Windows 7 workstation and use PuTTY for SSH connectivity to Linux servers with session logging enabled. I previously used the `Printable output` option but that has the *benefit* of no escape characters but the *drawback* of making commands I've typed unsearchable if I used `tab` to autocomplete or `backspace` because I corrected a typo (or 3) as I was typing the command.

**NOTE:** I have `cygwin` installed for additional command-line tool support (i.e. `grep`, `find`, etc.).

Recently, I had to go back and find some commands to set the record straight with a coworker about something that happened on a server and the inability to see the *final* commands I issued is problematic and makes it more difficult to search the logs as well as being much more difficult to readily demonstrate what actually happened for my coworker.

**Example #1:** 
This is an actual PuTTY log file of the 'pwd' command initially misspelled as 'pdw' and then corrected to 'pwd' with `Printable output` enabled when viewed with `cat` or in `less`.

**NOTE:** There is no difference between `less` and `cat` in this case because there are no `ESC` codes and only printable output was captured.

```
$ cat 20151112.170705.log
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2015.11.12 17:07:05 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
[root@eye ~]# pdwwd
/root
[root@eye ~]# exit
logout
$
```

As you can see, if you were to search for `pwd` you would get no matching results. I have used iTerm on Mac and know that it can automatically replay logs and it just seems like there should be a way to see the *end result* of what I eventually used.

Enter the PuTTY `All session output` logging option. Ok, so here is the deal, with `All session output` option enabled, the log file gets inundated with `ESC` codes for terminal color and non-printable characters like `backspace`.

**Example #2:**
This is an actual PuTTY log file of the 'pwd' command initially misspelled as 'pdw' and then corrected to 'pwd' with `All session output` enabled when viewed in `less`.

```
$ less 20151112.170457.log
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2015.11.12 17:04:57 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
Using username "root".
Authenticating with public key "ssh2_rsa_2048_private_key_20111128.ppk"
ESC[?1034hESC]0;root:~^GESC[1;30m[ESC[1;35mrootESC[1;30m@ESC[1;35meye ESC[1;34m~ESC[1;30m]ESC[1;35m# ESC[0mpdESC[ESC[Kwd
/root
ESC]0;root:~^GESC[1;30m[ESC[1;35mrootESC[1;30m@ESC[1;35meye ESC[1;34m~ESC[1;30m]ESC[1;35m# ESC[0mexit
logout
$
```

Ok, so I'm almost to the actual problem. If I use `cat` with `All session output` option enabled, it looks perfect. It is exactly what I want to see and work with.

**Example #3:**
This is an actual PuTTY log file of the 'pwd' command initially misspelled as 'pdw' and then corrected to 'pwd' with `All session output` enabled when viewed using `cat`.

**NOTE:** This is the exact same log file as above. This is also the exact visible output and format that I want to be able to search.

```
$ cat 20151112.170457.log
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2015.11.12 17:04:57 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
Using username "root".
Authenticating with public key "ssh2_rsa_2048_private_key_20111128.ppk"
[root@eye ~]# pwd
/root
[root@eye ~]# exit
logout

$
```

**The Real Problem I Need to Solve:**
How can I *programmatically* translate, convert, or update the content of these log files so that they *only* show what is actually visible to the user after processing the log file through `cat` command with `All session output` enabled in PuTTY session logging?

For the record, I have spent more than a few hours researching and testing possible solutions. Things I have tried which have not worked suitably (or at all):

- straight-forward redirect of `stdout` to a new file called test.log. The test.log was identical to the original log file. No benefit.

> ```
> $ cat 20151112.170457.log > test.log
> ```

- installing xclip and redirecting `cat` output to `xclip`. The `xclip` program complains because I don't have X11 support. Didn't work. No benefit.

> ```
> $ cat 20151112.170457.log | xclip
> Error: Can't open display: (null)
> ```

- using built-in Windows `clip` command. No complaints from the OS when I run this command, but it has the two problems below instead.

  - No programmatic way to get the data out of the Windows clipboard
  - Even if I could get the data out, the clipboard content is identical to the original log file (with `ESC` codes). No benefit.
- I do own a Mac and some of the other posts I read suggest using `pbcopy` but I'm skeptical it would work any different than 'clip' on Windows.
- I am aware of and have used `less -R` and `less -r` to allow handling of terminal color `ESC` codes (using `-R`) and all `ESC` codes (using `-r`) but, again, this only helps with presentation to the user and does not allow programmatic searching of hundreds of log files for the command `pwd` if I made a mistake and corrected it before pressing `Enter`.
- I also talked to coworker. No benefit. ;-)

In essence, I just want the PuTTY log equivalent of a copy/paste of a web page into notepad. The web page source has lots of `<html>` tags but the user doesn't see any of this and if they highlight the page, click `copy` and `paste` into Notepad, all they get is the text they saw on the page.

I want to be able to programmatically create the Notepad equivalent of all these PuTTY log files for effective searching (i.e. using `grep`).

**NOTE:** If it isn't obvious from my total StackExchange reputation of ***1***, this is my first question or post on StackExchange sites. I'm looking for helpful answers and not responses like "Switch to Linux" or "RTFM".

Comment: Is your .bash_history file not sufficient?

Comment: Definitely not. I didn't say it above, and not that it should matter, but I also administer another 50+ Cisco routers which don't have .bash_history. Plus, your comment doesn't really address my question. I specifically want to be able to search "cleaned up"putty logs without escape codes or control characters. There are so many reasons .bash_history is not acceptable... Not all in one place (if I don't know which server I was on), doesn't show output of commands, not private, etc.

Comment: Well, there are ways Cisco, Linux, and otherwise can be all configured to log commands to a central location, indexed with time stamps, source hosts, etc.

Comment: It still doesn't address my question.

Comment: Sometimes people post problems here, assuming they know what the answer should be (the XY problem) when in fact there is a much better way to solve the problem than they were initially aware of. So we ask clarifying questions. I'm not saying that's the case here, but that's the standard process I go through when I see a question like this.

Comment: @EEAA - I understand. I guess I just think your .bash_history suggestion addresses a completely different question than the one I've posed and so I feel that in no way have I assumed I knew what the answer should be. Rather, it seems like you may have thought you knew what my question should have been instead of the one I actually asked. However, I stand by my original question.

Comment: "Recently, I had to go back and find some commands to set the record straight with a coworker about something that happened on a server and the inability to see the final commands I issued is problematic" --- That problem could be easily solved using your shell history. Anyway, I was indeed making no assumptions about what your question should be. I was asking clarifying questions. That is all.

Comment: @EEAA - At least you're trying to help me, which is appreciated. Thanks for taking the time to read my question and comment.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the escape codes in the putty file are in binary(im a little confused why your example has control characters - im guessing less did that), you can try col

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/col.1.html

> The control sequences for carriage motion that col understands and
>          their decimal values are listed in the following table:

```
          ESC-7             reverse line feed (escape then 7)
          ESC-8             half reverse line feed (escape then 8)
          ESC-9             half forward line feed (escape then 9)
          backspace         moves back one column (8); ignored in the
                            first column
          newline           forward line feed (10); also does carriage
                            return
          carriage return   (13)
          shift in          shift to normal character set (15)
          shift out         shift to alternate character set (14)
          space             moves forward one column (32)
          tab               moves forward to next tab stop (9)
          vertical tab      reverse line feed (11)
```

Comment: It has taken me a long time to get back to this issue but I had a need again this morning and tried using 'col' command and it still does not work the way I need it to.

Comment: Any info why? It really should - it basically replays the control characters.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue logging a putty session and couldn't find any solution online either, so I ended up writing a small python script to read the session log and clean it up.

```
file_in=open('input.log')
file_out=open('output.log', 'w')

for line in file_in:
    input_line = bytearray(line, 'utf-8')

    input_line=input_line.replace(b"\x1b[J", b'')       #remove \x1b[J
    input_line=input_line.replace(b"\x1b[20D", b'')     #remove \x1b[20D
    input_line=input_line.replace(b"\x1b[H", b'')       #remove \x1b[H
    input_line=input_line.replace(b"\x1b[0m", b'')      #remove \x1b[0m
    input_line=input_line.replace(b"\x1b[0;0m", b'')    #remove \x1b[0;0m
    input_line=input_line.replace(b"\x1b[1;32m", b'')   #remove \x1b[1;32m
    input_line=input_line.replace(b"\x1b[1;34m", b'')   #remove \x1b[1;34m
    input_line=input_line.replace(b"\x1b[1;35m", b'')   #remove \x1b[1;35m
    input_line=input_line.replace(b"\x1b[1;36m", b'')   #remove \x1b[1;36m
    input_line=input_line.replace(b"\x1b[1m", b'')      #remove \x1b[1m
    input_line=input_line.replace(b"\x07", b'')         #remove \x07 (BEL)

    p = input_line.find(b"\x08")
    while p>0:                          #apply backspace and remove 'BS'
        del input_line[p]
        del input_line[p-1]
        p = input_line.find(b"\x08")

    file_out.write(input_line.decode())

file_in.close
file_out.close
```

This worked for my log. So enable 'All Session Output', give it a try and let me know.

Btw this is Python 3.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I came across your post looking for an answer to the same problem. You stated that if you cat the file it looks perfect. I used cat in CYGWIN to print out the file to the CYGWIN terminal then I selected everything and pasted it into a NotePad++ file. It worked perfectly.